# colspan not getting applied to column of table

Tags: html, angular

I am building an UI in angular application and need to do colspan for column called Subscriptions highlighted in the screenshot below. I tried applying colspan but doest seem to take effect.

[image]

What I need is something like this

[image]

Html

```
        <tr>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Class Name</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Last Edited</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Class ID</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold"></th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">TERMS</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">SUBSCRIPTIONS</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Primary Currency</th>

        </tr>



        <ng-container>
            <!-- <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue"> -->
            <tr *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel">
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.Description}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem"></td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.Id}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem"></td>
                <td class="tableItem"></td>
                <td colspan="5" class="tableItem"></td>
                <td class="tableItem"> 
                    <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.CurrencyId"
                     class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="Currencies"
                     [filterable]="false" textField="CURRENCY_NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="CURRENCY_ID">
                  </kendo-dropdownlist>
               </td>

            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
```

What gets generated on on inspect of the element . I have shared it across three screenshots as it was difficult to capture in one

Screenshot 1 - The header section

[image]

Screenshot 2 - The row section - Expanded

[image]

Screenshot 3 - The row section - Collapsed

[image]

Screenshot 4 of the entire table in collapsed view

[image]

Edit

I have tried the pseudo code suggested by @cpcolella in angular but need to display as seen in the screenshot above in the post

So It should display 
Legal Class Name Class A Class B Class C in one row

```
  <div *ngIf="LegalFundClasses && LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel && ColumnNames">


     <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
      <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
        <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel">
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Output of the logic above

[image]

Comment: Ehm, if you need one td to span 5 columns, why are there as many tds as there are ths in the source?

Comment: The requirement is that the records need to be displayed horizontally

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it could be because you need matching `th` elements to the `td` elements for it to work. Try putting a `th colspan="5"` at the same location, second to the last, in the `tr` above.

Comment: @pjlamb12 Ehm, no. The whole purpose of `colspan` is to be able to span more columns in one row than in another.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to span more columns than just one. But I'm pretty sure the number of columns in every row has to be the same as every other row or the layout gets messed up and it doesn't work. In this example in WE Schools it uses colspan but they each row has the same number of columns still. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: I tried applying colspan to both the td and th but it didnt work

Comment: @Tom can you provide what generated finally in inspect of browser?

Comment: @Saeed.Gh , I have added 4 screenshots in the post

Comment: try `<td [attr.colspan]="5" ...` or `<td [colSpan]="5" ...` and see if it works?!

Comment: None of them worked

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for it

Comment: Issue resolved. Please ignore

Answer (score 1):

You are generating the code wrong. I don't use angular, but the final table structure should look like this:

```
<table>

<tr>
<th class="tableItem bold">Legal Class Name</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class B</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class A</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class D</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class B</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class A</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class B1</th>
<th class="tableItem">Class C</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tableItem bold">Last edited</td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tableItem bold">Legal class ID</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
<td class="tableItem">123</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="tableItem bold">Subscription</td>
<td colspan = "7"> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I've only generated 3 rows. As you can see, each row has 8 column (like yours), except the last one, that has only 2, with one of them spanning 7 columns.

You should not use a for cycle for generating all rows, as the subscription row is different.

Comment: In angular all I am doing is using a for loop to dynamically generate the rows as  they would change from time to time. So I cant hard code the rows as mentioned in your solution

Comment: Then you can somehow check, inside the for loop, if the subscription row is being formatted. If yes, then use the colspan, if no, then use the regular formatting.

Comment: If you see in my code I am already doing this    <td colspan="7" class="tableItem"></td> then why isnt that working. This td is for subscriptions

Comment: Well, first of all, you are generating the table vertically (and it does not work like that). The tables in HTML are defined horizontally (first cell, second cell ... next row, ). You have to define the first row, then the second one and so on. You can see in my example that the first TR defines the row with headers, the second TR defines the row with Last Edited and so on. My example renders ok, you just have to implement the logic in angular, to have the same final result. Keep in mind that all the rows have the same structure, except for the subscription one (you need a IF to check that).

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to choose which direction tr and td go. tr is alwys a row. td and th are always cells that make a new column in that row. colspan lets one td or th take up multiple columns. Your table should prbasbly look something like this (though I am also not familiar with angular).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #EFF3FB;}

td:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #E7EFFE;}
```

```html
<table style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 25px;">

<tr>
<th class="tableItem bold">Legal Class Name</th>
<td class="tableItem">Class B</td>
<td class="tableItem">Class A</td>
<td class="tableItem">Class D</td>
<td class="tableItem">Class B</td>
<td class="tableItem">Class A</td>
<td class="tableItem">Class B1</td>
<td class="tableItem">Class C</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="tableItem bold">Last edited</th>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
<td class="tableItem"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="tableItem bold">Legal class ID</th>
<td class="tableItem">11166</td>
<td class="tableItem">11167</td>
<td class="tableItem">13714</td>
<td class="tableItem">13717</td>
<td class="tableItem">13713</td>
<td class="tableItem">13716</td>
<td class="tableItem">13715</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="tableItem bold">Subscription</th>
<td colspan = "7"> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408141/7724517

EDIT:
You'll need to have two loops. One through all of the horizontal headings and their associated field in the LegalClass object (outer) and one through all of the legal class objects (inner). The outer one will put the header item in first (for example: Legal Class Name) and the inner one will put the values for each legal class (in this example, the description). I hope this makes sense. This pseudo code is sort of like python.

```
FieldNames = {'Legal Class Name':'Description', 'Last Edited':'', 'Legal Class ID':'Id', 'TERMS':'', 'SUBSCRIPTIONS':'', 'Primary Currency':'CurrencyId'}
html = ""
foreach Field in FieldNames:
    html += "<tr> <th class="tableItem bold">Field.Key</th>"
    foreach LegalClass in LegalClassList:
        html += "<td class="tableItem">LegalClass.Field.Value</td>""
    html += "</tr>"
```

EDIT 2:
Something like this maybe. Again, I'm not proficient with angualar.

```html
<table>
  <ng-container>
    <tr *ngFor="let Row of Rows">
      <th class="tableItem bold">{{ Row.Header }}</th>
      <td *ngFor="let LFC of LegalFinancialClass" class="tableItem"> {{ LFC.Row.Value }} </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: In angular all I am doing is using a for loop to dynamically generate the rows as  they would change from time to time. So I cant hard code or define  the rows upfront as mentioned in your solution

Comment: @Tom notice though how each `tr` element has one `th` and each `td` in it is the same element of every Legal Class as opposed to how you have it where each `tr` contains a `td` for each of the fields in a Legal Class.

Comment: I am still struggling how to generate the way you suggested.

Comment: @Tom again i'm not familiar with angular but maybe i can do some pseudo code to help you out. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Please that will be helpful

Comment: @Tom I hope that helps you. Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: @Tom do you have something that rotates the table to be rendered sideways because otherwise that looks like it should work

Comment: also, adding something like this `<td class="tableItem" colspan="{{LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel.length}}" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[3]">{{f.Id}}</td>` assuming `RowNames[3]` is the Subscriptions item should give the desired result with the colspan issue.

Comment: were you ever able to get this figured out?